# Getting into Docker-machine host on DigitalOcean on new computer

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

My old MacBook died on me, and so did my public ssh keys /certs which I created a DigitalOcean droplet with docker-machine command, so now I can't connect to the droplet on my new computer.

I was wondering what would happen if I reset the root password of the droplet inside DigitalOcean dashboard? Would I be able to log into the droplet as root with the console and run an export of my postgresql database, so I could just import it to my new running droplet, or is there any way I could authenticate my new computer agains the old running docker-machine droplet without loosing the data on the host?

Comment: Is the data stored inside the container? When dealing with database we map the data to a volume separated the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the root password of you the droplet. After that, your droplet will be restarted, and the new password will email to you, and you can log in to your droplet again with the new password, but it will ask you for new password after the first login.